# Camera not working in android emulator 4.2.2, windows 8

Tags: android-emulator, android-camera

I am trying to use camera in android emulator but emulator gives error while starting :

Starting emulator for AVD 'android-4.2'
emulator: ERROR: camera_device_start_capturing: Device 'AndroidEmulatorVC0' is unable to save frame to the clipboard: 0
''
I set Back Camera as webcam0. The default camera app crashes when started.